# Why won't Xcode (10.1) realize this class? What am I doing wrong

Tags: c++

Basically trying to just run this program for extra learning, Xcode won't understand that I have written a class, and wont implement it. Really confused and need some guidance.

When I run the code only the main method is implemented, nothing else works...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class students {


    int id;
    char name[20];
    int s1;
    int s2;
    int s3;


public:


    void getData() {
        cout << "Enter the ID " << endl;
        cin >> id;
        cout << "Enter the name " << endl;
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Enter the grade in subject 1 " << endl;
        cin >> s1;
        cout << "Enter the grade in subject 2 " << endl;
        cin >> s2;
        cout << "Enter the grade in subject 3 " << endl;
        cin >> s3;
    }
    void putData() {
        cout << id << " " << name << " " << s1 << " " << s2 << " " << s3 << endl;


    }

};




int main () {

  students s[20];

    int i, n; //i is for the for loop, n for number of students

    cout << "Enter the number of students " << endl;
    cin >> n;

    for (i=0;i>n;i++)
    {
        s[i].getData();
    }
    for (i=0;i>n;i++)
    {
        s[i].putData();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Check the condition in your for loops.

Comment: Your problem is fairly trivial as highlighted by 1201ProgramAlarm, but you've not [debugged your program at all.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) meaning what you think is going wrong is unrelated to what is actually going wrong

Comment: The error that I'm receiving here is more-so that it's just running the main method, and it it'll return 0, asks me for the number of students and then quits program.


I also checked the conditions and they seem to be fine, but it just wont reference them. 

Also I'm not too sure how to debug the program I'm fairly new to coding just trying to get better :(

Comment: Wait I FIGURED IT OUT!!! I'm actually dumb lmao, it was i>n but it was supposed to be i < n!!!! Thanks for all the advice/assistance guys!